# Obtaining Orientation of Points to Another Layer?

Tags: qgis, geometry, points-to-line

I have a vector layer with points denoting receptors. I have a second vector layer (polygon) delineating a site boundary.  Utilizing QGIS v2.14, I am looking for a method to get the orientation of the points to the polygon. I.e. in degrees what is the orientation of each point to the site boundary polygon.

Comment: If you want the orientation in degrees, wouldn't it make more sense to add that as an attribute to the point layer?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: Hi, I'm utlising QGIS 2.14.  The query relates to having multiple points, but looking to get QGIS to supply an orientation to a polyline.  Thereby improving accuracy of results.  If this can be added to the points table through the field calculator, all the better.

Comment: @KGoodwin It's not clear if the orientation is towards a _polygon_ (as in the original question) or a _polyline_ (as in your last comment). Then, it would be enough evaluating the orientation towards the centroid of the polygon/polyline?

Comment: Sorry, the orientation is towards a polygon vector layer.  Your solution sounds good, but unfortunately I don't know how to go about doing it.